Can't get differential root to plot. What am I doing wrong?
I've been trying to solve a complicated system of differential equations. After some simplifying, I've executed the following and get a DifferentialRoot as output, but for some reason, I can't get it to plot. I've been sure to assign all constants a particular value.
DSolve[l1*(1 + 2*β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ])*f[θ] + (1/2)*l2*(1 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + 2*β^2*Cos[2*θ])*Sin[2*θ]*Derivative[1][f][θ] + l2*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + β^2*Cos[2*θ])*Sin[θ]^2*Derivative[2][f][θ] == 0, f[θ], θ]

The output is:
{
  {f[θ] -> C[2]*DifferentialRoot[Function[{Y, X}, {-4*X^2*l1*(2*X + 3*β + 3*\X^2*β + 4*X*β^2)*Y[X] + (-4*X^6*l2 + 6*X^3*l2*β - 6*X^7*l2*β + l2*β^2 - 3*X^8*l2*β^2 + X^4*(4*l2 + 2*l2*β^2))*Derivative[1][Y][X] - 
            (-1 + X)^2*X*(1 + X)^2*l2*(X + β + X^2*β)*(2*X+ β + X^2*β)*Derivative[2][Y][X] == 0, Y[2] == 0, Derivative[1][Y][2] == 1}]][E^(I*θ)] + 
     C[1]*DifferentialRoot[Function[{Y, X}, {-4*X^2*l1*(2*X + 3*β + 3*X^2*β + 4*X*β^2)*Y[X] + (-4*X^6*l2 + 6*X^3*l2*β - 6*X^7*l2*β + l2*β^2 - 3*X^8*l2*β^2 + X^4*(4*l2 + 2*l2*β^2))*Derivative[1][Y][X] - 
            (-1 + X)^2*X*(1 + X)^2*l2*(X + β + X^2*β)*(2*X + β + X^2*β)*Derivative[2][Y]][X] == 0, Y[2] == 1, Derivative[1][Y][2] == 0}]][E^(I*θ)]}}

I can't figure out how to plot over theta. The following doesn't return anything:
f[θ_] := C[2]*DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {-4*x^2*l1*(2*x + 3*β + 3*x^2*β + 4*x*β^2)*y[x] + (-4*x^6*l2 + 6*x^3*l2*β - 6*x^7*l2*β + l2*β^2 - 3*x^8*l2*β^2 + x^4*(4*l2 + 2*l2*β^2))*Derivative[1][y][x] - 
           (-1 + x)^2*x*(1 + x)^2*l2*(x + β + x^2*β)*(2*x + β + x^2*β)*Derivative[2][y][x] == 0, y[2] == 0, Derivative[1][y][2] == 1}]][E^(I*θ)] + 
    C[1]*DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {-4*x^2*l1*(2*x + 3*β + 3*x^2*β + 4*x*β^2)*y[x] + (-4*x^6*l2 + 6*x^3*l2*β - 6*x^7*l2*β + l2*β^2 - 3*x^8*l2*β^2 + x^4*(4*l2 + 2*l2*β^2))*Derivative[1][y][x] - 
           (-1 + x)^2*x*(1 + x)^2*l2*(x + β + x^2*β)*(2*x + β + x^2*β)*Derivative[2][y][x] == 0, y[2] == 1, Derivative[1][y][2] == 0}]][E^(I*θ)]; 

Plot[f[θ] /. {l1 -> 1, l2 -> 1, β -> 1.5, C[2] -> 1, C[1] -> 1}, {θ, 0, 1}]

This will take ages to compile and eventually the time constraint will run out. I've set my time constraint to infinity but it still doesn't work.
In case I posted it wrong, E^(I*θ) is supposed to be the exponential of the imaginary number times theta (Euler'ss identity).

better not use l1 and l2 for variables. They look like 11 and 12 on many screens depending on the font used. And it is also not a good idea to use 2 letters for a variable name specially when one is number and the other is not. Why not use say a and b for these? This will make the code more clear also.

It's also not a good idea to define your variable f to be a function later. Defining it to be a function means it cannot be used as the variable any more. Best to use \ different symbols for the variables and solution function.

The solution gives complex values. You can use Table command to generate values and then use ListPlot to plot either the real or the imaginary parts.
ode = a*(1 + 2*β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ])*f[θ] + (1/2)*b*(1 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + 
      2*β^2*Cos[2*θ])*Sin[2*θ]*f'[θ] + b*(1 + β^2 + 3*β*Cos[θ] + 
      β^2*Cos[2*θ])*Sin[θ]^2*f''[θ] == 0

sol = DSolve[ode, f, θ]


val = {a -> 1, b -> 1, β -> 1.5, C[2] -> 1, C[1] -> 1}
Table[f[θ] /. First[sol] /. val, {θ, 1, 2, 0.2}]

(*{4.56327 + 1.55118 I, 4.821 + 0.249869 I, 4.57799 - 1.09206 I, 
 3.67948 - 2.31667 I, 1.9675 - 2.8443 I, 2.77404 - 0.98958 I}*)

dataReal = Table[{θ, Re[f[θ] /. First[sol] /. val]}, {θ, 0,1, .1}]
dataIM = Table[{θ, Im[f[θ] /. First[sol] /. val]}, {θ, 0,1, .1}]

ListLinePlot[dataReal]


ListLinePlot[dataIM]



To plot a specific solution of such a difficult ODE, I'd suggest using NDSolve[].
ode = l1*(1 + 2*\[Beta]^2 + 3*\[Beta]*Cos[\[Theta]])*
     f[\[Theta]] + (1/2)*
     l2*(1 + 3*\[Beta]*Cos[\[Theta]] + 2*\[Beta]^2*Cos[2*\[Theta]])*
     Sin[2*\[Theta]]*Derivative[1][f][\[Theta]] + 
    l2*(1 + \[Beta]^2 + 
       3*\[Beta]*Cos[\[Theta]] + \[Beta]^2*Cos[2*\[Theta]])*
     Sin[\[Theta]]^2*Derivative[2][f][\[Theta]] == 0;

ics = {f[\[Theta]0] == f0, f'[\[Theta]0] == fp0};

Block[{l1 = 1, l2 = 1, \[Beta] = 1.5, (* parameters *)
  f0 = 1, fp0 = 1, \[Theta]0 = 1}, (* initial conditions *)
 eqn0 = ode;
 ListLinePlot[
  NDSolveValue[{eqn0, ics}, f, {\[Theta], 0, 1}],
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ]


NDSolveValue::ndsz: At \[Theta] == 2.7512375700871007`*^-11, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.


The singularity is to be expected, since the coefficient of f''[θ] vanishes at θ == 0.  Note that keeping things real is much easier with NDSolve[] than with DifferentialRoot[]. In some sense we're lucky to have such a sophisticated symbolic solution as DifferentialRoot[], but it's a bit hard to manage in this case.
The following shows a basis for the solution space over $0 \le \theta \le 1$:
Block[{l1 = 1, l2 = 1, \[Beta] = 1.5, (* parameters *)
  f0, fp0, \[Theta]0}, 
 eqn0 = ode;
 ListLinePlot[
  {f0 = 1; fp0 = 0; \[Theta]0 = 1; (* initial conditions *)
   NDSolveValue[{eqn0, ics}, f, {\[Theta], 0, 1}],
   f0 = 0; fp0 = 1; \[Theta]0 = 1; (* initial conditions *)
   NDSolveValue[{eqn0, ics}, f, {\[Theta], 0, 1}]},
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ]


< Two NDSolveValue::ndsz messages >



@MichealE2 your comment is beyond insightful for what I'm working on, thanks so much!
